# Make Error while Installing Ruby 1.9.2-180

Tags: ruby

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o ../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/tcltklib.bundle
stubs.o tcltklib.o -L. -L../.. -L/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/usr/lib -  L/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework -L. -L/usr/local/lib   -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tcl    -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -framework IOKit   -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tk -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1 -lm -ldl  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not      the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

I'm getting a make error:

```
Error running 'make', please read /Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

This is the same for p180. I have installed readline and everything already. I'm trying to install 1.9.3, with similar errors. I've tried installing with clang and readline flags, nothing works.

It appears that this is my main error:

```
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxslt.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which
is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: I think you need to rebuild libxslt.

Comment: Yeah, I rebuilt three libraries and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using OSX??
You can try use:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320 --with-gcc=clang
```

Or:

```
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320
```

Comment: I am using OSX. I have tried with clang (i'm installing p180, not p320) and it didn't work.

Comment: The second option doesnt work because that dir is not in my path

Comment: Are you have macports installed? If you have installed OpenSSL with macports you can have some problems.

Comment: I'm trying to install 1.9.3 now with no avail either

Comment: ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxslt.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64 - THIS seems to be my problem